# Application failed to register in Eureka throwing 404 null error

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have two application UI and backend service.

In Backend service added dependencies netflix-eureka client

While registering the backend service its throwing error as

```
2018-10-30 13:18:36.292 DEBUG 13572 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created POST request for "http://<<eureka_host:port>>/admin/instances"
2018-10-30 13:18:36.293 DEBUG 13572 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2018-10-30 13:18:36.294 DEBUG 13572 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [Application(name=App1, managementUrl=http://IN5CG52538Z0.CSCMWS.CSCMWS.COM:8282/actuator, healthUrl=http://IN5CG52538Z0.CSCMWS.CSCMWS.COM:8282/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://IN5CG52538Z0.CSCMWS.CSCMWS.COM:8282/)] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4cffd3fd]
2018-10-30 13:18:36.303 DEBUG 13572 --- [gistrationTask1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://<<eureka_host:port>>/admin/instances" resulted in 404 (null); invoking error handler
```

and  Zuul config as below

```
zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  ignore-security-headers: false
  routes:
cr:
 path: /api/app1/**
 serviceId: APP1
 strip-prefix: true
```

**/api/app1/users** --> POST method in backend service thrwoing 404 error when requested from UI application.

@EnableEurekaServer is added and eureka server is up and running.

my UI is angular 6 spring boot apaplication. Application that i have registered is UP in Eureka server(browser)

Application.yml `zuul:
  sensitive-headers:
  ignore-security-headers: false
  routes:
cr:
      path: /api/app1/**
      serviceId: APP1
      strip-prefix: true`
application.properties :
`eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true eureka.instance.hostName=APP1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${EUREKA_SERVER_HOSTNAME}/eureka/`

Comment: Have you enabled the Eureka server using `@EnableEurekaServer`? Where are the eureka properties defined? Please post them too.

Comment: Yes i have enabled Eureka server.  In application.yml   Server: port:8077 eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: http://${EUREKA_SERVER_HOSTNAME}/eureka
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${EUREKA_SERVER_HOSTNAME}/eureka/

Comment: Ans also in client application properties : eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.instance.hostName=APP1
#eureka.instance.hostName=localhost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${EUREKA_SERVER_HOSTNAME}/eureka/

Comment: can you add those configurations in the question as well. Would be easy for people to understand more. while writing code, select code part and format as code(menu with {} option)

Comment: Are you able to access the eureka from browser and see that no applications are up?In other words can you confirm eureka server is up and running?